# Delete local and remote cache

Tags: git, jenkins

I don't seem to have any git tags locally or in the remote because the following commands don't have any output:

```
git tag -l
git ls-remote --tags
```

However, my Jenkins build, which is creating a tag and pushing it to the remote fails with the following message:

```
The git-tag command failed.
Command output:
fatal: tag 'my-tag' already exists
```

The git tag creation is done under the hood so it's hard to test. I'm assuming some of the old tags may have been cached.

Is there some configuration kept by Git as a cache?

In which case, is there a way of clearing both the local and remote Git cache, just in case some old tags are kept there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly because Jenkins is trying to create the same tag more than once ***on its local git repo***. You can confirm this by running `git tag -l` on the Jenkins box. Presumably Jenkins hasn't pushed the tag to the origin because it is failing(?) and this is why you don't see it on the server.

Have Jenkins remove the tag every time before creating a tag:

```
git tag -d mytag
do some stuff
git tag mytag
git push
....
```

Then if it tries to recreate a tag with the same name you'll be assured that it is removed first.